# When XSLT for-each is in a loop. How can I add an attribute or node to that XML based on other XML value. USING XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Can any one help me to sort this problem?

I have an XML and filtering the values based on some condition. Storing the filtered xml in a variable. While filtering the condition, I'm trying to add an attribute or node to the filtered xml but it is not working for me..

Input XML:

```
    <root>
        <a id="13">
            <b>XXX1</b>
            <c>YYY1</c>
        </a>
        <a id="2">
            <b>XXX2</b>
            <c>YYY2</c>
        </a>
        <a id="15">
            <b>XXX3</b>
            <c>YYY3</c>
        </a>
        <a id="37">
            <b>XXX4</b>
            <c>YYY4</c>
        </a>
        <a id="51">
            <b>XXX5</b>
            <c>YYY5</c>
        </a>
    </root>
```

Another XML which is stored in a variable called "data" (this is for filtering):

```
<sample>
    <con id="37" order="1"/>
    <con id="13" order="2"/>
    <con id="51" order="3"/>
    <con id="2" order="4"/>
    <con id="15" order="5"/>
</sample>
```

Using XSLT, I'm trying to filter & add a element in this way.

```
<xsl:variable name="filteredData">
    <newroot>
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/a[@id > 14]">
        <xsl:if test="msxsl:node-set($data)/sample/con[@id = current()/@id]/@id = current()/@id">
          <xsl:element name="order">
            <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($data)/sample/con[@id = current()/@id]/@order"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </newroot>
</xsl:variable>
```

OUTPUT XML (i.e., "filteredData" variable should contain below XML):

```
     <newroot>
        <a id="15">
            <b>XXX3</b>
            <c>YYY3</c>
            <order>5</order>
        </a>
        <a id="37">
            <b>XXX4</b>
            <c>YYY4</c>
            <order>1</order>
        </a>
        <a id="51">
            <b>XXX5</b>
            <c>YYY5</c>
            <order>3</order>
        </a>
    </newroot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a lookup table with the key function as in this example [Tip: XSLT Lookup Table](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xsltip.html)

I was able to get the following snippet to produce an xml document which matched your output above. The filtering data in the xslt below has been loaded from a separate document but it should be easy to adapt.

```
<xsl:key name="id-lookup" match="con" use="@id"/>

<xsl:variable name="id-top" select="document('<lookup file>')/sample"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <newroot>
        <xsl:for-each select="a[@id > 14]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>

                <xsl:element name="order">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$id-top">
                        <xsl:with-param name="curr-label" select="."/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </newroot>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="sample">
    <xsl:param name="curr-label"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('id-lookup', $curr-label/@id)/@order"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @stoney: That's great. Thanks for the help and also for the URL which you suggested is much useful to me.

Comment: Glad to help. You should accept the answer by clicking the tick it it has answered your question and maybe even "up voting" using the arrow if your really happy.

Comment: This doesn't filter `a` elements on `con/@id` as in question, ending with posible empty `order` elements. In this situation it's better to traverse the filter (wich is shorter) rarer than the data.

Answer (score 1):

Based on inputs, now I tried & implemented with another form of representation.

New XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:variable name="filteredData">        
    <newroot>          
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/a[@id > 14]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
          <xsl:element name="Order">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="msxsl:node-set($data)/sample/con[@id = current()/@id]/@id = current()/@id">
                <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($data)/sample/con[@id = current()/@id]/@order"/>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </newroot>
  </xsl:variable>
```