# XSL Transformation - Merge elements

Tags: xml, xslt, review

I am trying to merge 2 xml files (as strings in the code).

```
<Root>
    <AMA>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="3"/>
            <Name type="UN">TOTO</Name>
            <Address>AAA</Address>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="4"/>
            <Name>TOTA</Name>
            <Address>BBB</Address>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="5"/>
            <Name>TOTQ</Name>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="6"/>
            <Name>TOTG</Name>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="7"/>
            <Name>TOTB</Name>
            <Address>CCC</Address>
        </Profile>
    </AMA>
    <External>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="3"/>
            <Miles>5</Miles>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="4"/>
            <Miles>4</Miles>
<Points>22222</Points>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="5"/>
            <Miles>3</Miles>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="6"/>
            <Miles>2</Miles>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
            <UniqueID id="7"/>
            <Miles>1</Miles>
        </Profile>
    </External>
</Root>
```

I want to obtain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Root>
    <Profile>
        <UniqueID id="3"/>
        <Name type="UN">TOTO</Name>
        <Address>AAA</Address>
        <Miles>5</Miles>
    </Profile>
    <Profile>
        <UniqueID id="4"/>
        <Name>TOTA</Name>
        <Address>BBB</Address>
        <Miles>4</Miles>
        <Points>22222</Points>
    </Profile>
    <Profile>
        <UniqueID id="5"/>
        <Name>TOTQ</Name>
        <Miles>3</Miles>
    </Profile>
    <Profile>
        <UniqueID id="6"/>
        <Name>TOTG</Name>
        <Miles>2</Miles>
    </Profile>
    <Profile>
        <UniqueID id="7"/>
        <Name>TOTB</Name>
        <Address>CCC</Address>
        <Miles>1</Miles>
    </Profile>
</Root>
```

I managed to write something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes" />
    <Root>
    <xsl:template match="/Root/AMA/Profile">
        <Profile>
            <xsl:for-each select=".">
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="/Root/External/Profile/UniqueID[@id=current()/UniqueID/@id]/../(Miles|Points)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Profile>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/root/External"/>
</xsl:transform>
    </Root>
```

How is it possible to avoid "hardcoding" the Profile node?

By "hardcoding" I mean "to not put the Profile element tag opening and closure my hand in the XML Transformation, but just copy the Profile node from the original one.

It seems another method exists, using the [XSLT Lookup Tables](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xsltip.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775813/when-xslt-for-each-is-in-a-loop-how-can-i-add-an-attribute-or-node-to-that-xml)... But it seems a little overkill.

Do you think there is a better solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is "hardcoding the Profile node"?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. You've shown us a single input document, rather than the two you say you're using, and you haven't really given us a good explanation of what you want the merge to do. And I agree with @KirillPolishchuk that it isn't clear what you mean by "hardcoding the Profile node" -- what do you want to do that the current approach can't do? Also, note that your stylesheet is ill-formed -- Root element doesn't nest properly, no root-node template to start the matching process but since it has a template it isn't a pull-style stylesheet. Stop and define the problem.

Comment: Yes, there is a better solution: use a **key** to lookup the external values. No, it has nothing to do with "*avoid "hardcoding" the Profile node*" - this part of your request is not clear, as others have already noted. -- Note also that `<xsl:for-each select=".">` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @keshlam I am merging 2 xml files wrapping them in a fake container root.

Comment: @michael.hor257k about the key lookup (mentioned in the links)... Why it should be better?

Comment: Because it's more efficient - sometimes dramatically so (see this recent example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177156/xslt-works-too-slow/26177529#26177529 ). IMHO, it's also easier to read.

Comment: Re your clarification: I can't see much difference between `<Profile>` and `<xsl:copy>` when your template matches `Profile` expressly.

Comment: @michael.hor257k potentially more complex if you have attributes in the Profile element in the original xml.

Comment: Makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do is to merge the `Profile` children of `AMA` and `External`.

You almost had it, but you need to move `Root`, remove the `xsl:for-each` and update the `select` in the second `xsl:copy-of`. (I moved the fixed path to the first `xsl:copy-of` in my example.)

Something like this... (assuming XSLT 2.0 because of `(Miles|Points)` in your XPath)

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--This will handle <Root/>-->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|AMA/Profile"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Root/AMA/Profile">
        <Profile>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()|
            /*/External/Profile[UniqueID/@id=current()/UniqueID/@id]/(Miles|Points)"/>
        </Profile>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you need to switch to XSLT 1.0, change `(Miles|Points)` to `*[self::Miles or self::Points]`

Comment: What about if the Miles and Points are in an inner element of Profile and I want to keep them at the same depth?