# XSLT works too slow

Tags: xml, performance, xslt

I have around 100 XML files which I want to transform into another file with a better structure. This example takes it into CSV, but I have also a variant that transforms it into better XML. Format is not that relevant for me. I see there are tons of questions like this, but I find the examples hard to adapt as the problem is not that the stylesheet wouldn't work but that it is too slow.

The sizes of my data files are between 4-12 MB. The XSLT I have provided here works well with small files. As an example, when I cut a file to 250 KB piece the stylesheet processes it well (though this takes already around 30 seconds). When I try it to the actual larger data file it just never seems to finish the job - not even with one file. I have Oxygen XML Editor, I've been using Saxon-HE 9.5.1.2 for the transformation.

One remark: this can still be slowish. I can leave my computer to do it for overnight or something. This concerns one malformed dataset and I don't need to repeat this transformation often at all.

So my question is:

**Is there something in this XSLT that makes it work particularly slowly? Would some other approch work better?**

These are simplified working examples. The actual data files are structurally identical, but have more nodes which I called "words" in this example. The attribute **type** specifies which nodes I'm after. It is linguistic dialect data with dialectal words and their normalized versions.

This is the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<order>
    <slot id="ts1" value="1957"/>
    <slot id="ts2" value="1957"/>
    <slot id="ts3" value="2389"/>
    <slot id="ts4" value="2389"/>
    <slot id="ts5" value="2389"/>
    <slot id="ts6" value="2389"/>
    <slot id="ts7" value="3252"/>
    <slot id="ts8" value="3252"/>
    <slot id="ts9" value="3252"/>
    <slot id="ts10" value="3360"/>
</order>
<words type="original word">
    <annotation>
        <data id_1="ts1" id_2="ts3">
            <text>dialectal_word_1</text>
        </data>
    </annotation>
    <annotation>
        <data id_1="ts4" id_2="ts7">
            <text>dialectal_word_2</text>
        </data>
    </annotation>
    <annotation>
        <data id_1="ts8" id_2="ts10">
            <text>,</text>
        </data>
    </annotation>
</words>
<words type="normalized word">
    <annotation>
        <data id_1="ts2" id_2="ts5">
            <text>normalized_word_1</text>
        </data>
    </annotation>
    <annotation>
        <data id_1="ts6" id_2="ts9">
            <text>normalized_word_2</text>
        </data>
    </annotation>
</words>
</xml>
```

This is the XSLT. What it attempts to do is to pick up the pairs which have matching values up in the XML structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:text>original&#x9;normalized
</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="words[@type='original word']/annotation/data">
            <xsl:sort select="substring-after(@id_1, 'ts')" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:variable name="origStartTimeId" select="@id_1"/>
            <xsl:variable name="origEndTimeId" select="@id_2"/>
            <xsl:variable name="origStartTime_VALUE" select="/xml/order/slot[@id=$origStartTimeId]/@value"/>
            <xsl:variable name="origEndTime_VALUE" select="/xml/order/slot[@id=$origEndTimeId]/@value"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>    
                <xsl:for-each select="/xml/words[@type='normalized word']/annotation/data">
                    <xsl:variable name="normStartTime" select="@id_1"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="normEndTime" select="@id_2"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="normStartTime_VALUE" select="/xml/order/slot[@id=$normStartTime]/@value"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="normEndTime_VALUE" select="/xml/order/slot[@id=$normEndTime]/@value"/>
                    <xsl:if test="($normStartTime_VALUE = $origStartTime_VALUE) and ($normEndTime_VALUE = $origEndTime_VALUE)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="text"/>    
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is outputs is simply this:

```
original    normalized
dialectal_word_1    normalized_word_1
dialectal_word_2    normalized_word_2
,
```

And that would be fine for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The double nested for-each in your current stylesheet is inefficient and will get worse as the size of the file grows - you've got (number of original words)*(number of normalized words) iterations, essentially quadratic complexity (assuming there's roughly the same number of original and normalized words in the file).  You can do much better if you use *keys*, which work by building a lookup table that you can use to find nodes very quickly (typically in constant rather than linear time).

```
<!-- I've said version="2.0" to match your stylesheet in the question, but this
     code is actually valid XSLT 1.0 as it doesn't use any 2.0-specific features
     or functions -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- first key to look up slot elements by their id -->
  <xsl:key name="slotById" match="slot" use="@id" />
  <!-- second key to look up normalized word annotations by the value of their slots -->
  <xsl:key name="annotationBySlots" match="words[@type='normalized word']/annotation"
           use="concat(key('slotById', data/@id_1)/@value, '|',
                       key('slotById', data/@id_2)/@value)" />

  <xsl:template match="/xml">
    <xsl:text>original&#x9;normalized&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="words[@type = 'original word']/annotation" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="annotation">
    <xsl:value-of select="data/text" />
    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="
            key('annotationBySlots',
                concat(key('slotById', data/@id_1)/@value, '|',
                       key('slotById', data/@id_2)/@value)
            )/data/text" />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should run in linear time (one "iteration" per *original* word annotation, plus the time taken to build the lookup tables which again should be linear in the number of slots plus the number of *normalized* word annotations).

Comment: This works great, thanks for the explanation too! Just to report the outcome: processing time went to something between less than a second and maybe a couple of seconds with the largest files.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that some processors (Saxon-EE is an example) are capable of performing this optimization automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Constructs like `/xml/order/slot[@id=$origStartTimeId]` ask for defining a key `<xsl:key name="slot-by-id" match="xml/order/slot" use="@id"/>` and then using `key('slot-by-id', $origStartTimeId)` instead of `/xml/order/slot[@id=$origStartTimeId]`. Make the same change in all places and I am sure performances increases.